# How to show a fancy 404 page and recording/emailing all exception to Admin

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am on Laravel 5.1.

Whenever there is an exception, Laravel usually shows an exception on the page. I'd like to add a custom 404 page with a human readable error report and email an admin with the entire error dump. I would also like to have the email nicely formatted in HTML (like on the error page).

How can I do this?

Comment: Try adding the file `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

Comment: @dan-klasson not a complete answer

Comment: i would make a error log watchdog..

Comment: @hanshenrik log is already being made, need to intimate instantly to Admins.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first part for displaying fancy 404 comes with adding 404.blade.php to resources/views/errors.

Regarding emailing the error_dump, this requires a way to catch the error events. Here's how to handle that. In the file `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`, add the email code to your `report()` method

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $e)
{



if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        //Send email here 
    }

return parent::report($e);
}
```